# Div to ignore html tags

Tags: html

I want that just one of my divs ignores all containing in it html tags such as `<br/>`'s, `<p>`'s and `<b>`'s. How's this possible? Thank you!

Comment: I think you need a `code` tag instead.

Comment: what do you mean by ignoring? do you want to show those actual tags as usual text or you want to ignore them completely?

Answer (score 8):

If the HTML tags you wish to ignore are currently static text, do a find and replace of (in this order):

```
Find     Replace
-----------------
&        &amp;
<        &lt;
```

If the HTML tags you wish to ignore are outputted using PHP, use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on the output and use UTF-8 to encode your page.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($stringThatContainsHTML, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: You'll need to replace `<` with `&lt;` too. Replacing `>` with `&gt;` is optional though.

Comment: i have a div <div>line1 <br /> line2</div> and i want this to be displayed like "line1 line2" ;)

Comment: please, a solution without php

Comment: Read the first part of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your question and see how Stackoverflow do it.

You'll see that `<br/>`, `<p>` and `<b>` are in a `code` element.

Comment: i have a div <div>line1 <br /> line2</div> and i want this to be displayed like "line1 line2" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Encode your html entities:

```
< … &lt;
> … &gt;
& … &amp;
" … &quot;
(' … &apos; xml, not html. see comments)
```

You might also want to use

```
<pre><code>
    here comes your preformatted and escaped &lt;html&gt;-code
</code></pre>
```

to have your code monospaced and preserve whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such things in HTML. You can use JavaScript to modify the document tree, replacing element nodes by their contents or by manipulating the `innerHTML` property. Of course, search engines and friends would still “see” the tags you make browsers ignore.

Alternatively, you can use CSS to nullify the effect of tags on rendering, but this only affects presentation (when CSS is enabled), not any functionality that browsers might have for some elements. And it would need to be different for different elements. For the tags mentioned in the question, assuming that your `div` element has `class=ignoreTags`, for definiteness, the following would nullify any normal effect on visual rendering they would have:

```
<style>
.ignoreTags br { display: none; }
.ignoreTags p  { display: inline; margin: 0; }
.ignoreTags b  { font-weight: normal; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some hack that might be working

```
<input value='<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">stack</a><br> <b>My</b> text' />
```

- design the input size as you wish